# No Output When using AWK

Tags: awk

I currently am making a script that check printer status. The outputs are Printer Color, Max Level, Current Level, and Current Percentage. The problem I am having is when trying to filter the color from the command. When I specify `/.*\.6\.1\./` or `/.*\.6\.1/` or `/.*\.6/` I get no output from the CL. My Code currently only works when I specify something like `/.*\.6\.1\.1/` or `/.*\.6\.1\.3/`, then I get the output of the first or x color obviously but I want the output of all colors. I was wondering if I was doing this wrong and if there was anyway to fix it?

Needed Filtered:

```
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.2.1.1 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.2.1.2 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.2.1.3 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.2.1.4 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.2.1.5 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.2.1.6 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.2.1.7 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.3.1.1 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.3.1.2 = INTEGER: 2
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.3.1.3 = INTEGER: 3
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.3.1.4 = INTEGER: 4
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.3.1.5 = INTEGER: 5
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.3.1.6 = INTEGER: 6
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.3.1.7 = INTEGER: 7
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.6.1.1 = STRING: "CyanInkCartridge"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.6.1.2 = STRING: "MagentaInkCartridge"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.6.1.3 = STRING: "YellowInkCartridge"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.6.1.4 = STRING: "MattBlackInkCartridge"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.6.1.5 = STRING: "MattBlackInkCartridge"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.6.1.6 = STRING: "BlackInkCartridge"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.6.1.7 = STRING: "WasteInkTank"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.7.1.1 = INTEGER: 15
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.7.1.2 = INTEGER: 15
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.7.1.3 = INTEGER: 15
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.7.1.4 = INTEGER: 15
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.7.1.5 = INTEGER: 15
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.7.1.6 = INTEGER: 15
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.7.1.7 = INTEGER: 15
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.1 = INTEGER: 1300
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.2 = INTEGER: 1300
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.3 = INTEGER: 1300
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.4 = INTEGER: 1300
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.5 = INTEGER: 1300
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.6 = INTEGER: 1300
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.7 = INTEGER: 10000
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.1 = INTEGER: 1300
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.2 = INTEGER: 780
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.3 = INTEGER: 780
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.4 = INTEGER: 780
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.5 = INTEGER: 780
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.6 = INTEGER: 1300
iso.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.7 = INTEGER: 4000
```

Current Code:

```
#!/bin/sh

snmpwalk -v1 -c public $1 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1 | awk '

/.*\.6\.1\.1/ {
  sub(/.*\./,"");
  split($0,TT,/[ "]*/);
  color[TT[1]]=TT[4];
}

/.*\.8/ {
  sub(/.*\./,"");
  split($0,TT,/[ "]*/);
  maxlevel[TT[1]]=TT[4];
}

/.*\.9/ {
  sub(/.*\./,"");
  split($0,TT,/[ "]*/);
  if ((TT[4] / maxlevel[TT[1]] * 100) < 50){
  print "\033[31m Color: " color[TT[1]] ", Current Level: " TT[4] ", Max Level: " maxlevel[TT[1]] ", Percentage: %" TT[4] / maxlevel[TT[1]] * 100 "\033[0m";
  }else{
  print "\033[32m Color: " color[TT[1]] ", Current Level: " TT[4] ", Max Level: " maxlevel[TT[1]] ", Percentage: %" TT[4] / maxlevel[TT[1]] * 100 "\033[0m";

}
}
'
```

Command: `./PrintInfo 192.168.15.102`

Current Output:

```
 Color: CyanInkCartridge, Current Level: 1300, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %100
 Color: , Current Level: 780, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %60
 Color: , Current Level: 780, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %60
 Color: , Current Level: 780, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %60
 Color: , Current Level: 780, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %60
 Color: , Current Level: 1300, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %100
 Color: , Current Level: 4000, Max Level: 10000, Percentage: %40
```

Desired Output:

```
 Color: CyanInkCartridge, Current Level: 1300, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %100
 Color: MagentaInkCartridge, Current Level: 780, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %60
 Color: YellowInkCartridge, Current Level: 780, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %60
 Color: MattBlackInkCartridge, Current Level: 780, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %60
 Color: MattBlackInkCartridge, Current Level: 780, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %60
 Color: BlackInkCartridge, Current Level: 1300, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %100
 Color: WasteInkTank, Current Level: 4000, Max Level: 10000, Percentage: %40
```

The desired output is to have all of the colors listed above instead of just one color. The problem with this as I have stated above is that when I try doing this buy changing the code `/.*\.6\.1\./` instead of `/.*\.6\.1\.1/` the Command Line does not show any output at all and also does not give me an error. What am I doing wrong that may cause something like this?

Comment: What is your expected result/output for the example input you provided?

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts, could you please do add more details in your post, like more clear sample of input and sample of expected output and let us know then?

Comment: @zedfoxus Updated code to show desired outputs and provided inputs

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Updated code to show desired outputs and provided inputs

Comment: @BLAKE, good you added expected output but still logic is not clear by which you want to get expected output so please add that too and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The desired output is to have all of the colors listed above instead of just one color. The problem with this as I have stated above is that when I try doing this buy changing the code /.*\.6\.1\./ instead of /.*\.6\.1\.1/ the Command Line does not show any output at all and also does not give me an error. What am I doing wrong that may cause something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the first part of *all* of your lines match `/.*\.6\.1\./`.

If you instead change it to something like this so that it only matches color lines,

```
/11.*\.6\.1\./ {
```

You get:

```
 $ awk -f a.awk file
 Color: CyanInkCartridge, Current Level: 1300, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %100
 Color: MagentaInkCartridge, Current Level: 780, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %60
 Color: YellowInkCartridge, Current Level: 780, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %60
 Color: MattBlackInkCartridge, Current Level: 780, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %60
 Color: MattBlackInkCartridge, Current Level: 780, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %60
 Color: BlackInkCartridge, Current Level: 1300, Max Level: 1300, Percentage: %100
 Color: WasteInkTank, Current Level: 4000, Max Level: 10000, Percentage: %40
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than what you're currently doing, start with this and then massage to suit:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[. ]"; OFS=", " }
{ vals[$11][$13] = $NF }
END {
    for (id in vals[6]) {
        sep = ""
        for (attr in vals) {
            printf "%s%s", sep, vals[attr][id]
            sep = OFS
        }
        print ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1, 1, "CyanInkCartridge", 15, 1300, 1300
1, 2, "MagentaInkCartridge", 15, 1300, 780
1, 3, "YellowInkCartridge", 15, 1300, 780
1, 4, "MattBlackInkCartridge", 15, 1300, 780
1, 5, "MattBlackInkCartridge", 15, 1300, 780
1, 6, "BlackInkCartridge", 15, 1300, 1300
1, 7, "WasteInkTank", 15, 10000, 4000
```

The above uses GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays, easily tweaked for any awk if necessary.